# Evaluate over a two-dimensional domain, the integral of (hypergeometric-based) $ f(d,k) $, the result for $ f(d,0) $ being known

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

I view this as both a mathematics and a *Mathematica* question -- so apologies if it is thought I should have sent it alternatively to the mathematics stack exchange.

I want to perform the two-dimensional integration (or, possibly, reduce to a one-dimensional integration)

```
Integrate[Y^(-1 + d)
   Hypergeometric2F1Regularized[d/2, -k, (2 + d)/
   2, ((Y^2 - e^2 Subscript[r, 14]^2) (-1 + e^2 Subscript[r, 14]^2))/(
   e^2 (Y^2 - Subscript[r, 14]^2) (-1 + Subscript[r, 14]^2))] (1/(
   e Subscript[r, 14]))^(
  1 + d) (1 + Y^2 (1 - 1/Subscript[r, 14]^2) - Subscript[r, 14]^2)^
  k (1 - e^2 Subscript[r, 14]^2)^(
  d/2) (-Y^2 + e^2 Subscript[r, 14]^2)^(d/2), {Subscript[r, 14], 0, 
  1}, {Y, e Subscript[r, 14]^2, e Subscript[r, 14]}, 
 Assumptions -> d >= 1 && k >= 0 && 0 < e <= 1]
```

So, $ d $ and $ k $ are parameters, and $ Y $ and $ r_{14} $ the variables of integration, with $ e $ being a free variable.

In $ \mathrm\TeX $, the integrand is the product of

\begin{equation}
Y^{d-1} \left(\frac{1}{r_{14} \epsilon }\right){}^{d+1} \left(1-r_{14}^2 \epsilon
   ^2\right){}^{d/2} \left(\left(1-\frac{1}{r_{14}^2}\right) Y^2-r_{14}^2+1\right){}^k
   \left(r_{14}^2 \epsilon ^2-Y^2\right){}^{d/2}
\end{equation}

and

\begin{equation}
\, _2\tilde{F}_1\left(\frac{d}{2},-k;\frac{d+2}{2};\frac{\left(r_{14}^2 \epsilon
   ^2-1\right) \left(Y^2-r_{14}^2 \epsilon ^2\right)}{\left(r_{14}^2-1\right) \epsilon ^2
   \left(Y^2-r_{14}^2\right)}\right)   .  
\end{equation}

The two-dimensional domain of integration is

\begin{equation}
r_{14} \in [0,1], \hspace{.25in}  Y \in [\varepsilon   r_{14}, \varepsilon^2   r_{14}]  .
\end{equation}

For $ k=0 $, the integral evaluates (as can be  confirmed by setting $ d $ to 
a positive integer -- even integers evaluate more readily) to

```
1/4 e^(-1 + d)
  Gamma[d/2] Gamma[
  d] HypergeometricPFQRegularized[{-(d/2), d/2, d}, {1 + d/2, 
   1 + (3 d)/2}, e^2]
```

That is, 
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{4} \epsilon ^{d-1} \Gamma \left(\frac{d}{2}\right) \Gamma (d) \,
   _3\tilde{F}_2\left(-\frac{d}{2},\frac{d}{2},d;\frac{d}{2}+1,\frac{3 d}{2}+1;\epsilon
   ^2\right).
\end{equation}

I've been trying all possible integration-by-parts combinations with no success to this point in time.

For even, nonnegative $ d $ and nonnegative $ k $, the integrand evaluates to a polynomial in $ e $. For odd $ d $, logs and polylogs appear.

The question stated here pertains to the issue discussed in sec. IX.B of my [posting](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.10680), *Qubit-qudit separability/PPT-probability investigations, including Lovas-Andai formula advancements*, 
of finding an "extended Lovas-Andai master formula", denoted there by $ \tilde{\chi}_{d,k}(\varepsilon) $.

Comment: I have posted a related question on the mathematics stack exchange site https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2744828/find-five-parameter-values-for-a-3-tildef-2-function-yielding-five-polynomi

Answer (score 2):

Charles F. Dunkl has provided me with essentially the answer to the bivariate ($r_{14}, r_{23}$) integration question at hand. (However, I had brought to his attention, a problem with a slightly reexpressed integrand, using a change-of-variables, now designated $x,y$. Also, I had omitted  certain accompanying [gamma,...] factors, not functions of the two variables, from the stated problem for the sake of conciseness. These are now present in his write-up. The important parameters $d,k$ and (not integrated out) variable $\varepsilon$ remain. (Let me note that CFD works in Maple.)

I now provide his write-up (certain of the TeX commands do not seem to "take" in this stack-exchange setting). The central problem is the evaluation of $I(\varepsilon)$, which is given near the end.

Let us simplify
\begin{align*}
I\left(  \varepsilon\right)    & :=\frac{\Gamma\left(  1+d+k\right)  ^{2}%
}{\Gamma\left(  \frac{d}{2}\right)  ^{3}\Gamma\left(  1+\frac{d}{2}+k\right)
\Gamma\left(  1+k\right)  }\times\frac{2}{d}\varepsilon^{-d}\\
& \times\int_{0}^{1}dx\int_{\varepsilon^{2}x}^{\varepsilon^{2}}dy[\left\{
\left(  1-x\right)  \left(  1-y\right)  \right\}  ^{k}\left(  xy\right)
^{d/2-1}\left\{  \left(  \varepsilon^{2}-y\right)  \left(  1-x\varepsilon
^{2}\right)  \right\}  ^{d/2}\\
& \times~_{2}F_{1}\left(  -k,\frac{d}{2};1+\frac{d}{2};T\right)  ]\\
T  & :=\frac{\left(  \varepsilon^{2}-y\right)  \left(  1-x\varepsilon
^{2}\right)  }{\left(  1-x\right)  \left(  1-y\right)  \varepsilon^{2}}.
\end{align*}
First we apply the transformation $_{2}F_{1}\left(  a,b;c;t\right)  =\left(
1-t\right)  ^{-a}~_{2}F_{1}(a,c-b;c;\frac{t}{t-1}$), but the series on the
right side only converges if $a$ is a negative integer or $t<\frac{1}{2}$, not
the case in our application, thus \textbf{henceforth assume} $k=0,1,2,3,\ldots
$then%
\begin{align*}
1-T  & =\frac{\left(  1-\varepsilon^{2}\right)  \left(  y-x\varepsilon
^{2}\right)  }{\left(  1-x\right)  \left(  1-y\right)  \varepsilon^{2}},\\
\frac{T}{T-1}  & =-\frac{\left(  \varepsilon^{2}-y\right)  \left(
1-x\varepsilon^{2}\right)  }{\left(  1-\varepsilon^{2}\right)  \left(
y-x\varepsilon^{2}\right)  };
\end{align*}
the integrand becomes%
\begin{align*}
& \left(  xy\right)  ^{d/2-1}\left(  1-\varepsilon^{2}\right)  ^{k}%
\varepsilon^{-2k}\left(  y-x\varepsilon^{2}\right)  ^{k}\left(  1-x\varepsilon
^{2}\right)  ^{d/2}\left(  \varepsilon^{2}-y\right)  _{~}^{d/2}\\
& \times~_{2}F_{1}\left(  -k,1;1+\frac{d}{2};-\frac{\left(  \varepsilon
^{2}-y\right)  \left(  1-x\varepsilon^{2}\right)  }{\left(  1-\varepsilon
^{2}\right)  \left(  y-x\varepsilon^{2}\right)  }\right)  .
\end{align*}
Substitute $y=\varepsilon^{2}u$ so $dy=\varepsilon^{2}du$ and $0\leq x\leq
u\leq1.$ This gives a factor of $\varepsilon^{2d}$ in front of%
\begin{align*}
& \int\limits_{0\leq x\leq u\leq1}\int dx~du~\left(  xu\right)  ^{d/2-1}\\
& \sum_{j=0}^{k}\frac{\left(  -k\right)  _{j}}{\left(  1+\frac{d}{2}\right)
_{j}}\left(  -1\right)  ^{j}\left(  1-x\varepsilon^{2}\right)  ^{d/2+j}\left(
1-u\right)  ^{d/2+j}\left(  1-\varepsilon^{2}\right)  ^{k-j}\left(
u-x\right)  ^{k-j}.
\end{align*}
Isolate the $x$-integral (use the negative binomial series for $\left(
1-x\varepsilon^{2}\right)  ^{d/2+j}$)%
\begin{align*}
& \int_{0}^{u}x^{d/2-1}\left(  u-x\right)  ^{k-j}\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}%
\frac{\left(  -\frac{d}{2}-j\right)  _{i}}{i!}x^{i}\varepsilon^{2i}dx\\
& =\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(  -\frac{d}{2}-j\right)  _{i}}{i!}%
\frac{\Gamma\left(  \frac{d}{2}+i\right)  \Gamma\left(  k-j+1\right)  }%
{\Gamma\left(  \frac{d}{2}+i+k-j+1\right)  }\varepsilon^{2i}u^{d/2+i+k-j},
\end{align*}
by use of $\int_{0}^{u}x^{\alpha-1}\left(  u-x\right)  ^{\beta-1}%
dx=u^{\alpha+\beta-1}B\left(  \alpha,\beta\right)  $. The inner $u$-integral
is%
[
\int_{0}^{1}u^{d/2-1}u^{d/2+i+k-j}\left(  1-u\right)  ^{d/2+j}du=\frac
{\Gamma\left(  d+i+k-j\right)  \Gamma\left(  \frac{d}{2}+j+1\right)  }%
{\Gamma\left(  \frac{3d}{2}+i+k+1\right)  }.
]
Thus the integral is%
\begin{align*}
& \sum_{j=0}^{k}\frac{\left(  -k\right)  _{j}}{\left(  1+\frac{d}{2}\right)
_{j}}\varepsilon^{2d}\left(  1-\varepsilon^{2}\right)  ^{k-j}\left(
-1\right)  ^{j}\\
& \times\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(  -\frac{d}{2}-j\right)  _{i}}{i!}%
\frac{\Gamma\left(  \frac{d}{2}+i\right)  \Gamma\left(  k-j+1\right)  }%
{\Gamma\left(  \frac{d}{2}+i+k-j+1\right)  }\varepsilon^{2i}\frac
{\Gamma\left(  d+i+k-j\right)  \Gamma\left(  \frac{d}{2}+j+1\right)  }%
{\Gamma\left(  \frac{3d}{2}+i+k+1\right)  }\\
& =\sum_{j=0}^{k}\frac{\left(  -k\right)  _{j}}{\left(  1+\frac{d}{2}\right)
_{j}}\left(  -1\right)  ^{j}\varepsilon^{2d}\left(  1-\varepsilon^{2}\right)
^{k-j}\frac{\Gamma\left(  \frac{d}{2}\right)  \Gamma\left(  k-j+1\right)
\Gamma\left(  d+k-j\right)  \Gamma\left(  \frac{d}{2}+j+1\right)  }%
{\Gamma\left(  \frac{d}{2}+k-j+1\right)  \Gamma\left(  \frac{3d}%
{2}+k+1\right)  }\\
& \times\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(  -\frac{d}{2}-j\right)  _{i}\left(
\frac{d}{2}\right)  _{i}\left(  d+k-j\right)  _{i}}{i!\left(  \frac{d}%
{2}+k-j+1\right)  _{i}\left(  \frac{3d}{2}+k+1\right)  _{i}}\varepsilon^{2i}.
\end{align*}
The last sum is a $_{3}F_{2}$ with argument $\varepsilon^{2}.$

Simplify the Gamma terms and note $\left(  -k\right)  _{j}=\left(  -1\right)
^{j}\frac{k!}{\left(  k-j\right)  !}$ and $\Gamma\left(  k-j+1\right)
=\left(  k-j\right)  !.$ Then%
\begin{align*}
& \frac{\left(  -k\right)  _{j}}{\left(  1+\frac{d}{2}\right)  _{j}}\left(
-1\right)  ^{j}\frac{\Gamma\left(  \frac{d}{2}\right)  \Gamma\left(
k-j+1\right)  \Gamma\left(  d+k-j\right)  \Gamma\left(  \frac{d}%
{2}+j+1\right)  }{\Gamma\left(  \frac{d}{2}+k-j+1\right)  \Gamma\left(
\frac{3d}{2}+k+1\right)  }\\
& =\frac{k!}{\left(  1+\frac{d}{2}\right)  _{j}}\frac{\Gamma\left(  \frac
{d}{2}\right)  \Gamma\left(  \frac{d}{2}+1\right)  \left(  \frac{d}%
{2}+1\right)  _{j}\Gamma\left(  d\right)  \left(  d\right)  _{k-j}}%
{\Gamma\left(  \frac{d}{2}+1\right)  \left(  \frac{d}{2}+1\right)
_{k-j}\Gamma\left(  \frac{3d}{2}+1+k\right)  }\\
& =\frac{k!\left(  d\right)  _{k-j}\Gamma\left(  \frac{d}{2}\right)
\Gamma\left(  d\right)  }{\left(  \frac{d}{2}+1\right)  _{k-j}\Gamma\left(
\frac{3d}{2}+1+k\right)  }.
\end{align*}
Combine the factors (correctly +/- ??)%
\begin{align*}
I\left(  \varepsilon\right)    & =\frac{2\Gamma\left(  1+d+k\right)
^{2}\Gamma\left(  \frac{d}{2}\right)  \Gamma\left(  d\right)  k!\varepsilon
^{d}}{d\Gamma\left(  \frac{d}{2}\right)  ^{3}\Gamma\left(  1+\frac{d}%
{2}+k\right)  \Gamma\left(  1+k\right)  \Gamma\left(  \frac{3d}{2}+1+k\right)
}\\
& \times\sum_{j=0}^{k}\frac{\left(  d\right)  _{k-j}}{\left(  \frac{d}%
{2}+1\right)  _{k-j}}\left(  1-\varepsilon^{2}\right)  ^{k-j}~_{3}F_{2}\left(
%
%TCIMACRO{\QATOP{-d/2-j,d/2,d+k-j}{1+d/2+k-j,1+k+3d/2}}%
%BeginExpansion
\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{-d/2-j,d/2,d+k-j}{1+d/2+k-j,1+k+3d/2}%
%EndExpansion
;\varepsilon^{2}\right)  .
\end{align*}
The first line simplifies to%
[
\frac{\Gamma\left(  1+d+k\right)  ^{2}\Gamma\left(  1+d\right)  }%
{2\Gamma\left(  1+\frac{d}{2}+k\right)  \Gamma\left(  1+\frac{d}{2}\right)
^{2}\Gamma\left(  1+\frac{3d}{2}+k\right)  }\varepsilon^{d}%
]
(apparently agrees with the postulated $k=0$ expression)